# Missing required parameters for route (Laravel8)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm attempting to edit someone's premade script since the original owner hasn't updated it for a couple years and I'm unable to get in contact them. I think the script is written in Laravel but I don't know what version they used. For now it doesn't seem to work in the latest laravel version 8

Now my problem is when I try to login it will give error:

> Illuminate \ Routing \ Exceptions \ UrlGenerationException Missing
> required parameters for [Route: dashboard.profiles.show] [URI:
> dashboard/{profile}].

Does anyone know how to fix this? here are some files that I think is related to the error

web.php route

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('social/{provider}', 'Auth\SocialiteController@redirectToProvider')->name('auth.socialite');
Route::get('social/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\SocialiteController@handleProviderCallback');

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('about', 'PageController@about')->name('pages.about');
Route::get('privacy', 'PageController@privacy')->name('pages.privacy');
Route::get('terms', 'PageController@terms')->name('pages.terms');
Route::get('press', 'PageController@press')->name('pages.press');

Route::get('l/{uid}', 'LinkController@show')->name('links.show');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::view('subscribe', 'subscribe');

    Route::get('account', 'UserController@edit')->name('users.edit');
    Route::patch('account', 'UserController@update');
    Route::patch('account/password', 'UserController@changePassword');

    Route::post('referral/invites', 'ReferralController@invites')->name('referral.invites');
});

Route::get('sitemap.xml', 'SitemapController@sitemap')->name('sitemap');

Route::get('{profile}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

dashboard.php route

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified'], function () {
    Route::get('profile/create', 'ProfileController@create')->name('profiles.create');
});

// api
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/{profile}'], function () {
    Route::get('/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
    Route::put('/update', 'ProfileController@update');
    Route::post('/create', 'ProfileController@store');

    Route::put('theme/update', 'ProfileController@update');

    Route::put('/links/create', 'LinkController@store');
    Route::delete('/links/{link}', 'LinkController@destroy');
    Route::put('/links/{link}', 'LinkController@update');
    Route::put('/links/{link}/resort', 'LinkController@resort');
});

Route::get('{profile}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profiles.show');
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param Profile $profile
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show(Profile $profile)
    {
        $profile->viewed();

        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no route `dashboard.profiles.show` available, but only `profiles.show` ...
which might be a typo in the Blade template, which generates the link by named route.
The error message means: accessing a named route, which had not been registered.
`UrlGenerationException` should not be thrown when referring to a known route.

It might generally be easier to pass `int $id` instead of `Profile $profile`. So how are you going to convert that `object` into `string` URL ?? `{profile}` does not appear to be a viable approach.

---

I'd write it whole different (notice the singular form):

```
Route::get('/dashboard/profile', [
      'as' => 'profile.show',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@show'
]);

Route::get('/profiles/{id}', [
      'as' => 'profile.show',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@show'
]);
```

With a method signature eg. alike this (it could also be two methods):

```
/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return View
 */
public function show(int $id): View {
    if (isset($id)) {
        /* process parameter ID */
    } else {
        /* the own ID: Auth::user()->id */
    }
}
```

And then look up the user ID in `ProfileController` (if required). Passing an `{id}` parameter only makes sense when viewing other profiles than the current user's profile - there's no right or wrong, but the controller should handle this; route parameters are not necessarily required. `int $id` is convenient, because Eloquent also uses `int $id`; therefore it's almost as good as the model instance `Profile $profile` itself. Consistent grammar for the route names makes life easier ...because `'profiles.show'` rather sounds alike a listing of `N` items, than a detail view of `1`.

---

The registered routes can also be listed with:

```
php artisan route:list
```